# GWT load bulk data when scroll down with RPC

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

i wish to show bulk data like [cell list](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) , but my problem is , i want to show 50 records (i will load 50 data to cell list) when user scroll downs my RPC service will load 25 more.On the example above ,we have to load all data but i do not want to load whole the data to cell list , i wish to load more when user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using the following approach

1) Capture the index of the last record showing in the Cell list.
   This parameter helps us to query the next set of records.

2) Fire an Event when the user scrolls down to the position, where you want to load more records

3) Handle the event, in that hit your RPC service with index of the last showing record.

4) Change your RPC service to handle the index(last shown record index) parameter.

5) Once the response is received, update the cell list with new records, 
   while updating you should append the newly received data to the existing cell list data.

Comment: Actually i tried the example that i have provided on above , and used AsynDataProvider , everything was fine over here. Now just one thing is missing , i can load more data with onRangeChange method but it is not triggering by scrolling down , it can only trigger with pressing down button on cell list

Answer (score 0):

i did it with  example [example](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) , i just put my own function to ShowMorePagerPanel custom class.

```
 public ShowMorePagerPanel() {
initWidget(scrollable);

// Do not let the scrollable take tab focus.
scrollable.getElement().setTabIndex(-1);

// Handle scroll events.
scrollable.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
  public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
    // If scrolling up, ignore the event.
    int oldScrollPos = lastScrollPos;
    lastScrollPos = scrollable.getVerticalScrollPosition();
    if (oldScrollPos >= lastScrollPos) {
      return;
    }

    HasRows display = getDisplay();
    if (display == null) {
      return;
    }
    int maxScrollTop = scrollable.getWidget().getOffsetHeight()
        - scrollable.getOffsetHeight();
    if (lastScrollPos >= maxScrollTop) {
      // now we can add more data
      **createData(); // creates 30 more data with RPC service**
      int newPageSize = Math.min(
          display.getVisibleRange().getLength() + incrementSize,
          display.getRowCount());
      display.setVisibleRange(0, newPageSize);
    }
  }
});
```

}